# want to know if any of provider(i.e. network or WiFi) is in use

Tags: android, location, shared-libraries

Currently I'm working with little fluffy lib.

As this Lib. uses Passive Provider then if no other application using network/GPS is running It's not sending any updates.
And frequency of updating location is also change after few updates.

I'm testing on Samsung POP with android 2.2.1

So, I want to know that is any other application using network or GPS in my device. so, that I can change provider to active from Passive (currently use by little fluffy lib.).
Can I get through any API or class from android SDK the list of application which are using GPS or network.

thanks in advance...